# Custom 500 error getting blank page sometimes

Tags: django, error-handling, http-status-code-500

When I try to test the custom 500 error page. If the test works, the I get a blank page with nothing on it ("Internal Server Error") in my error logs. If an error occurs, I get custom error page.

In views:

```
def handler500(request):
    response = render_to_response("500.html")
    response.status_code = 500
    return response

def my_test_500_view(request):
    # Return an "Internal Server Error" 500 response code.
    return HttpResponse(status=500)
```

In Urls.py:

```
my path is : path('test500/', views.my_test_500_view, name='test500')
```

Also:

```
handler500 = 'myapp.views.handler500'
```

If I actually create an error like by removing the import line for the HttpResponse from the my_test_500_view above, the custom 500 error page actually loads and I get this error on the server, i.e. the actual error.

```
NameError: name 'HttpResponse' is not defined
```

What's wrong with my test that it returns a blank page. Is my 500 page actually working? I think it's not working right, since I got a email warning from google search about failure of 500 error page and I often get this error:

```
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Please help, what's going on.

Comment: Your `urls.py` file seems to be incorrect, you're probaly passing a string path of the view, not the view function itself to the `path` call, see the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example).

Please provide the full content of the `urls.py`.

Comment: Okay, how would you change the url. I've tried lots of different things - i.e. like with and without the name, what would you suggest I do?

Comment: @Alex, so you think the error page handling is working, but the URL is wrong?

Comment: Please provide the whole `urls.py` file in order to determine what actually causes the problem. It is hard to say without seeing it

Comment: @Alex, the way that I setup this path is how I have set up all paths in the view. It generally has worked for other views: For instance home is: path('home/', views.home, name='home') and this works with a def function named 'home' in views. What are you actually looking for in the urls.py file? Everything related to this view I've included, the handler, etc.

Comment: Note: your `TypeError` at the end of your question is probably unrelated to this. Submit another question with the full stack trace if you can't figure out where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning an `HttpResponse(status=500)` does not cause Django to call the `handler500` view, it just returns a blank page (you didn't specify any content in `HttpResponse`) and sets status 500 on the response headers.

If you want to test your `handler500`, just `raise` an exception in your test view. Any exception will do.